# Download & rename file from URL through macro in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to download a list of dropbox images links and want to rename the files with new name.

What I want to achieve is if i put the new file name in one cell and the link in the another one it should download the file, rename it and save at the file path mentioned in the FILE PATH to save. If there is any error while downloading the image the status will be updated in the status cell.

For Example:

[image]

I will be using this macro on MS Office professional plus 2016 64 bit Win 10.

I am trying the below macro but it is not saving the image:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

'~~> This is where the images will be saved. Change as applicable
Const FolderName As String = "C:\Temp\"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String

    '~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
        strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"

        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
        Else
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, i guess the question was not clear so i updated it and repost

Comment: Let me edit the question again, i will share the macro which i am trying to get it work

Comment: Dumb question I guess--but are you sure you can reach the URL?  I mean have you checked that you can download the file _outside_ Excel to insure that there's not some other issue?

Comment: Yes I have checked the url is working fine outside the excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be an issue with the function declaration for 64bit.
Try

```
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
   (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
   (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If
```

**Update**: If the download fails, the function returns an error code. However, if the file can be downloaded but cannot be written locally (eg invalid filename, no write permission...), the function returns 0.

Comment: I have changed the function declaration but the image is not downloading.

Comment: No error code it is showing the status as downloaded but the file is not there in the folder

Comment: And you have write access to the folder? Instead of `C:\Temp`, try `environ("Temp")`. This will write the file into your personal Temp-folder (where you have write access for sure). I did a test: There is no error thrown when attempting to write to an invalid folder

Comment: Now i am getting an error. sharing the sample file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GDsNAKmkSd8PInAfT6amzCIGjyFEGWam/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For me, the 2 files throw (different) errors. Dropbox throws a timeout. Amazon, I think doesn't like it if you try to download a product image. However, I was able to download 2 other files with the code - so likely the problem is not the code itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204072/discussion-between-sameer-farooqui-and-funthomas).

Comment: Glad to hear. Would be nice to update and accept the answer.